# Printing a string in based on a probability

Tags: python, scipy, stat

I would like to know if there is a python package or method to print a string probability after execution. For example,

```py
print("TEST") # probability of 50%, and you execute the line 10 times

OUTPUT:
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
TEST
-
-
-
-
-
```

The `-` would just mean that if you execute the command nothing happens. I was pretty sure there is a way of doing this in `stats` but kind of forgot. Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for [numpy.random](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html)?

Answer (score 0):

you could do this using `random` module, it will print `"TEST"` with a 50% chance, else it will print `"-"` :

```
from random import randint
def command():
    print("TEST") if randint(0,1) else ...
for _ in range(10):
    command()
```

Comment: This code produces an error

Comment: fixed, thanks!!

Comment: Now it just doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This does not execute the print 10 times nor does it do nothing with 50% probability.

Comment: still doesn't do nothing with 50% probability

Comment: it does literally the same thing as yours did but it gives '-' as output when it doesn't display the "TEST" message.

Comment: yes but he asked for the program to do nothing instead.

Comment: ok, i have "fixed" it, but it was just for displaying that it will do it 50% of the times.

Comment: Fair, but he may not have known about `. . .`.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use this:

```
from random import randint
for n in range(10):
    if randint(0,1):
        print("TEST")
```

It will print "TEST" with 50% probability and do nothing otherwise 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [random.choice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) with an array of 2 functions to achieve your goal:

```py
import random

def func1():
    print("TEST")

def func2():
    pass

for n in range(10):
    random.choice([func1, func2])()
```